# PHP Mysql get users by groupid

Tags: php, mysql, join

This is actually a pretty straight forward problem I just can't seem to think about how to do it right now. Alright so I have two tables Users and Groups on my landing page I have a dropdown that displays all of the groups each group has a group leader which is a user. So in my groups table I have the fields id,groupid,leaderid. leaderid connects to users.id I need to loop through the groups and grab/join the leader's information if anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You described the task very well, where is the problem?

Comment: I've always sucked at joins I was wondering if someone could help, I tried to different joins and they didn't work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` statement to link the two tables together.

```
SELECT groups.groupid, users.name
FROM groups
JOIN users ON users.id = groups.leaderid
```

Comment: Awesome i was using Inner join which messed things up.

Comment: Do you have any good recommendations for learning joins better?

Comment: A `JOIN` actually defaults to `INNER JOIN`, so there shouldn't be a difference in those two queries. To learn joins better, I don't have any specific recommendations (others can chime in), but a Google search for "mysql join tutorial" should help.